# Xcode Phonegap build errors: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am getting these errors every time that I start a new project in xcode 4.3.  I cannot figure out how to get rid of them since the file is in the directory.  I left ARC off when starting the project.  Can some one help me.

```
chmod: /Users/AB/Dropbox/Clients/Foreign: No such file or directory
chmod: Car: No such file or directory
chmod: Services/Mobile: No such file or directory
chmod: Application/xcode/foreignCarServies/verify.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/AB/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foreignCarServies-hkikistryyiksohlfphsfvjcrimy/Build/Intermediates/foreignCarServies.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/foreignCarServies.build/Script-204C9E7A152BED2200A80E8B.sh: line 4: /Users/AB/Dropbox/Clients/Foreign: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It is NOT xCode. Xcode is not an iPhone. My eyes hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a "run script" build phase in which you are doing a `chmod`.

Find that phase and delete it.

If it happens with every new project, it sounds like your templates somehow got messed up.